# Operator Precedence

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

I have a sample midterm question that I am not too sure about. Here it is:

```
#include <iostream.h>

void f( int i )
{
 if( i = 4 || i = 5 ) return;
 cout << "hello world\n" ;
}

int main()
{
f( 3 );
f( 4 );
f( 5 );
return 0;
}
```

So I understand that the logical OR operator has a higher precedence and that it is read left to right. I also understand that what's being used is an assignment operator instead of the relational operator. I just dont get how to make sense of it all. The first thing the compiler would check would be `4 || i`? How is that evaluated and what happens after that?

Comment: Who would write code like that?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Since it's in an exam question, I assume that the bugs is there intentionally, and the point is for the student to spot the bug.

Comment: This shouldn't compile since `4 || i` is not an l-value.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Where is `true` being used as an l-value?

Comment: @cdhowie - Shows how bad exams are when you see `#include <iostream.h>`

Comment: @cdhowie: Rather I should say, `4 || i` (the result of which is `true`) is not an l-value (comment fixed).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Ah, interesting. I've not used `||` and `=` together this way (for good reason, of course) and wasn't aware that assignment had higher precedence. Though I guess that makes sense.

Comment: This is a weird midterm question. I dont even think this would compile. I think it would complain about l-values

Comment: See here: http://ideone.com/JHqk7k  I think that the question first appeared some time ago (maybe close to 20 years ago) and never has been updated to modern/ANSI standards.

Comment: @cdhowie: It's the opposite. `||` has higher precedence.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Clearly I did not get enough sleep last night. Right concept in my head, wrong word came out.

Answer (score 8):

Let's add all the implied parentheses (remembering that `||` has higher [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `=` and that `=` is right-associative):

```
i = ((4 || i) = 5)
```

So, it first evaluates `4 || i`, which evaluates to `true` (actually, it even ignores `i`, since `4` is `true` and `||` short-circuits). It then tries to assign `5` to this, which [errors out](http://ideone.com/7cNqnk).

Comment: @VladfromMoscow No, I don't (and I do hope you mean it in jest).

Comment: It looks very strange because in fact you even did not yet type your answer when it was already upvoted.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow That doesn't make much sense. He had to have typed out his answer first for it to *be* an answer to upvote.

Comment: @0x499602D2 It makes sense because it seems he has a support group.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I'm sure there are other reasons. For example: he has high rep, is a good frequent answerer and has a large about of badges. The psychology of upvoting has been discussed in meta.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I've experienced caching/latency issues with the server which manifested in similar symptoms (a new answer loading already upvoted).

Comment: @ 0x499602D2 No other reasons because it is not the first time when this is repeated even when his answer is worse than others.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Flag me for mod attention, then. I have nothing to hide.

Comment: @Angew I am not going to flag anybody. I simply take into account that there are dishonest men.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I don't like being falsely accused, but I don't think I can do anything to convince you. Think what you will.

Answer (score 3):

As written, the code doesn't compile, since operator precedence means it's `i = ((4 || i) = 5)` or something, and you can't assign to a temporary value like `(4 || i)`.

If the operations are supposed to be assignment `=` rather than comparison `==` for some reason, and the assignment expressions are supposed to be the operands of `||`, then you'd need parentheses

```
(i = 4) || (i = 5)
```

As you say, the result of `i=4` is 4 (or, more exactly, an *lvalue* referring to `i`, which now has the value 4). That's used in a boolean context, so it's converted to `bool` by comparing it with zero: zero would become `false`, and any other value becomes `true`.

Since the first operand of `||` is true, the second isn't evaluated, and the overall result is true. So `i` is left with the value 4, then the function returns. The program won't print anything, whatever values you pass to the function.

It would make rather more sense using comparison operations

```
i == 4 || i == 5
```

meaning the function would only print something when the argument is neither 4 nor 5; so it would just print once in your example, for `f(3)`.

Note that `<iostream.h>` hasn't been a standard header for decades. You're being taught an obsolete version of the language, using some extremely dubious code. You should get yourself a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242) and stop wasting time on this course.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler shall isuue an error because expression `4 || i` is not a lvalue and may not be assigned.

As for the expression itself then the value of it is always equal to `true` because 4 is not equal to zero.